# How to start a storyboard which is attached to a control inside a data template?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a storyboard inside a data template. I want to start this only for a certain condition. In my case whenever the no. of seconds in the clock is 59 the storyboard should start.

Below you can see the storyboard as well as the control to which the animation is applied :

```
<!-- Minute Hand -->
                <Image
                    Source="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource MinHandBackground}}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"                        
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"                        
                    Canvas.Left="118"
                    Canvas.Top="118">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform
                                X="-11"
                                Y="-90" />

                            <RotateTransform
                                x:Name="minHandTransform" />


                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>

                    <Image.Triggers>


                        <EventTrigger
                            RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard
                                    x:Name="myStoryboard2">
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        x:Name="minuteAnimation"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="minHandTransform"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                        Duration="0:0:1"
                                        From="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource minuteHandTransform}}"
                                        To="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource minuteHandToTransform}}"
                                        RepeatBehavior="1x">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <SineEase
                                                EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>

                    </Image.Triggers>
                </Image>
```

Currently the BeginStoryboard starts it immediately on load. I want to start it when the number of seconds is 59 but i cant access the storyboard in the back end as the control is within a data template.

Can anyone please help me out here.....i have been banging my head about this problem for a lot of days now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to move the entire contents of the DataTemplate to a separate UserControl so you would get easier access to all named elements.

Comment: Your answer seems to be a good way to do it as well, but jerry's answer might be more useful for others so i marked it. Anyway unfortunately, it didnt solve my actual problem even after being able to access the storyboard in the backend. Please take a look at this question and let me know if u can think of a solution, thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273506/how-to-animate-at-periodic-intervals

Comment: I ended up using ur suggestion and shifted everything to a UserControl and it works great. Thanks